# A singular matrix limit

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits

This limit

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\left(A+\frac{B}{\varepsilon}\right)^{-1}$$

for an invertible matrix $B$ is a null matrix (since it breaks down to $\varepsilon\cdot B^{-1}\to\bf{0}$)

> The real question is - what this limit in terms of $A$ and $B$ is when $B$ is singular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Fredrik Meyer, the limit can be practically anything. This can be summarised in the following proposition:

> **Proposition 1.** Given any $C\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, $C=\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to0}\left(A+\frac{B}{\varepsilon}\right)^{-1}$ for some matrix $A$ and some singular matrix $B$.

*Proof.* By considering its singular value decomposition, we may assume WLOG that $C=\operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_k,0,\ldots,0)$. Take $A=C^+=\operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1^{-1},\ldots,\sigma_k^{-1},0,\ldots,0)$ and $B=\operatorname{diag}(0,\ldots,0,1,\ldots,1)$ (with $n-k$ trailing ones), we are done.

However, if $B$ is prespecified, there are limitations on what $A$ and $C$ can be:

> **Proposition 2.** Let $B=U(\Sigma\oplus0_{(n-k)\times(n-k)})V^\ast$ be a singular value decomposition of $B$, where $\Sigma$ is a $k\times k$ positive diagonal matrix with $k<n$ (hence $B$ is singular). Let also $C=V\begin{pmatrix}C_{11}&C_{12}\\C_{21}&C_{22}\end{pmatrix}U^\ast$, where the partitioning conforms to the block structure of $B$. Then $C=\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to0}\left(A+\frac{B}{\varepsilon}\right)^{-1}$ for some matrix $A$ if and only if $C_{11},C_{12},C_{21}$ are zero blocks and $C_{22}$ is invertible.

*Proof.* WLOG, suppose $U=V=I$. For the "if" part, just take $A=C^+=0\oplus C_{22}^{-1}$. For the "only if" part, let $A=\begin{pmatrix}P&Q\\R&S\end{pmatrix}$ and $P_\varepsilon=P+\frac{\Sigma}{\varepsilon}$. Then $P_\varepsilon$ is invertible when $\varepsilon$ is sufficiently small. Furthermore, as $A+\frac{B}{\varepsilon}=\begin{pmatrix}P_\varepsilon&Q\\R&S\end{pmatrix}$ and $C=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0} \left(A+\frac{B}{\varepsilon}\right)^{-1}$, the Schur complement $S-RP_\varepsilon^{-1}Q$ must be invertible for all sufficiently small $\varepsilon$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
&\left(A+\frac{B}{\varepsilon}\right)^{-1}
=\begin{pmatrix}P_\varepsilon&Q\\R&S\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\\
=&\begin{pmatrix}
P_\varepsilon^{-1}+P_\varepsilon^{-1}Q(S-RP_\varepsilon^{-1}Q)^{-1}RP_\varepsilon^{-1} & -P_\varepsilon^{-1}Q(S-RP_\varepsilon^{-1}Q)^{-1}\\
-(S-RP_\varepsilon^{-1}Q)^{-1}RP_\varepsilon^{-1} & (S-RP_\varepsilon^{-1}Q)^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
As $C_{22}=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}(S-RP_\varepsilon^{-1}Q)^{-1}$, $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}1/\det(S-RP_\varepsilon^{-1}Q)$ exists. Since $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}P_\varepsilon^{-1}=0$, we see that $\det(S)\not=0$. Therefore $C_{11},C_{12},C_{21}$ are zero blocks and $C_{22}=S^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

It can probably be almost anything. Consider for example the case when $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$ Then one calculates that the limit $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} (A+\frac{B}{\epsilon})^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \neq 0.$

Another example is of course when $B$ is the zero matrix. Then the limit is $A^{-1}$ (if it exists).

You can even have it go to zero if even if $B$ is singular. Take for example $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$. Then the limit is $0$, even if $B$ wasn't invertible.

Comment: @Kaster, that's what's wanted, no? The question asks, what if $B$ is singular?

Comment: You're right, I didn't read his question carefully. Deleted that post.

Comment: I still wonder whether _almost anything_ is generated by a formula of some kind (that is why I am not rushing the acceptance of this answer).